# .htaccess redirect from subdomain to main

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I, using .htaccess, redirect people from subdomain to the main with php get? for example:

> hi.example.com > example.com/website.php?name=hi

If you enters a php file it will add it to get, for example:

> hi.example.com/contect.php >
>   example.com/website.php?name=hi&page=contect

And if you have more info, so it will add it to the url, for example:

> hi.example.com/contect.php?action=success#messege >
>   example.com/website.php?name=hi&page=contect&action=success#messege

`hi` and `contect` are only examples and I want that every other name will work. for example:

> my-page.example.com/pageno1.php >
>   example.com/website.php?name=my-page&page=pageno1

all the subdomain **does** exist

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?hi\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/website.php?name=hi [R=301,L]
```

Or if you have query strings then use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?hi\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/website.php? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `'hi' and 'contect' are only examples and I want that every other name will work.`. There are a lot of subdomains, and I want that the users will think that they are really surfing in the subdomain. You also doesn't included the second option `hi.example.com/contect.php > example.com/website.php?name=hi&page=contect`

Comment: you can replace them according to your names

Comment: The problems is that all the subdomain is redirecting to the main domain (but the url stays the same), so is there a way with `^(.*)$` and all of this stuff `:D` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !name=[^&]+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/website.php?name=%1 [R,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !name=[^&]+    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ http://example.com/website.php?name=%1&page=$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It makes me a loop, and it redirects to `http://web-gen.net/website.php?webname=web-gen&pagename=website&from=subdomain&webname=web-gen&pagename=website&from=subdomain&webname=web-gen&pagename=website`... even if I enters to the main domain (not the subdomain). The main domain doesn't have www for the SSL

Comment: now it is working except when you are in the main domain. Is there a way to cancel it for the main domain only? because now it is redirects me, when I'm in the main domain to `http://web-gen.net/website.php?webname=web-gen&via=subdomain&pagename=index`

Comment: And still doesn't work. Again, is there a way to disable if to the **whole** main domain? Thank you by the way `:D`

Comment: `ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`. Look, my website has a lot or redirection so I think that your code will stop it, no?

Comment: Sorry I need to leave now since it is pretty late now. For 500 you can check your Apache error.log